# Spring MVC 4.1.x RestFul Service throwing Not Acceptable for Json

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-mvc

I have made a Rest Service using Spring MVC4.1.X, but whenever I try to return Json o/p to browser iam getting the following error

**The resource identified by this request is only capable of generating responses with characteristics not acceptable according to the request "accept" headers.**

Iam using @Response body for auto conversion of a Java pojo into JSON objects. I have tried almost all the solution given on stackoverflow .

```
my controller class 
package com.spring.rest.ambulance;

import java.io.IOException;

import net.sf.json.JSONObject;

import org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.spring.dao.AmbulanceDAO;
import com.spring.dao.AmbulanceDAOImpl;
import com.spring.model.Ambulance;


@RestController
@RequestMapping("/Ambulance")
public class AmbulanceRestController {
    @Autowired
    private AmbulanceDAO ambulanceDAO;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/hello", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody String getAllUsers(ModelMap model) {
        String jsonData = "[{\"id\":\"3253123\",\"firstname\":\"Chris\",\"lastname\":\"Johnson\",\"address\":\"211, Geoffrey Drive\",\"city\":\"Newark\",\"phone\":\"999-888-6666\",\"email\":\"chrisj@yahoo.com\"},{\"id\":\"67643837\",\"firstname\":\"Bill\",\"lastname\":\"Derkson\",\"address\":\"201, Sleepy Hollow Drive\",\"city\":\"Newark\",\"phone\":\"999-777-2222\",\"email\":\"billd@gmail.com\"}]";
        return jsonData;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/{id}")
    public @ResponseBody Ambulance getAmbulanceProviders(ModelMap model,
            @PathVariable("id") int Id) {
        String jsonData = null ;
        Ambulance ambulance = ambulanceDAO.getById(Id);
        ObjectMapper objmapper = new ObjectMapper();
        try {
             jsonData = objmapper.writeValueAsString(ambulance);
            //System.out.println(objmapper.writeValueAsString(ambulance));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return ambulance;
    }

Entity being returned 
package com.spring.model;

import org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper;

public class Ambulance {

    private int ID;
    private String vehicleNumber;
    private String ambulanceType;
    private String ambulanceProviderName;
    /**
     * @return the iD
     */
    public int getID() {

        return ID;
    }

    /**
     * @param iD
     *            the iD to set
     */
    public void setID(int iD) {
        ID = iD;
    }


    /**
     * @return the vehicleNumber
     */
    public String getVehicleNumber() {
        return vehicleNumber;
    }

    /**
     * @param vehicleNumber
     *            the vehicleNumber to set
     */
    public void setVehicleNumber(String vehicleNumber) {
        this.vehicleNumber = vehicleNumber;
    }

    /**
     * @return the ambulanceType
     */
    public String getAmbulanceType() {
        return ambulanceType;
    }

    /**
     * @param ambulanceType
     *            the ambulanceType to set
     */
    public void setAmbulanceType(String ambulanceType) {
        this.ambulanceType = ambulanceType;
    }

    /**
     * @return the ambulanceProviderName
     */
    public String getAmbulanceProviderName() {
        return ambulanceProviderName;
    }

    /**
     * @param ambulanceProviderName
     *            the ambulanceProviderName to set
     */
    public void setAmbulanceProviderName(String ambulanceProviderName) {
        this.ambulanceProviderName = ambulanceProviderName;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "{ID="+ID+",AmbulanceProvderName="+ambulanceProviderName+",AmbulanceType="+ambulanceType+",VehicleNumber="+vehicleNumber+"}";
    }

}

    DAO Ambulance get by Id
    public Ambulance getById(int id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Ambulance ambulance = new Ambulance(); 
    /*  JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate =  new JdbcTemplate();
        System.out.println(dataSource);
        jdbcTemplate.setDataSource(dataSource);*/
        System.out.println(jdbcTemplate.getDataSource());
        String sql = "SELECT * FROM AMBULANCE WHERE AMBULANCEID = ?";
        ambulance = (Ambulance)jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(sql,new Object[] { id }, new AmbulanceRowMapper());


        return ambulance;
    }


pom.xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>SpringWebAppRestServices</groupId>
    <artifactId>SpringWebAppRestServices</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.5</version>
    </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: How are you making the rest call? HTML form? Postman?

Comment: Did you add '@EnabledWebMvc' in your config class?: The new '@EnableWebMvc' annotation does a number of useful things – specifically, in the case of REST, it detect the existence of Jackson and JAXB 2 on the classpath and automatically creates and registers default JSON and XML converters

Comment: And specify the response type to produce like this: @RequestMapping(value = "/hello", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)

Comment: You don't need @ResponseBody on your methods since your controller is already annotated with `@RestController`. Also, you definitely should add a produces="application/json" attribute in your `@RequestMapping`, otherwise you're solely relying on content negotiation and default media types, although your methods clearly only produce JSON. Last thing, you need to update your jackson dependency as MasterSlave pointed out.

Comment: Hi @BrianClozel I have added the jackson dependency in POM.but still iam etting the same error . Also i have added the Produces attribute to json . I am calling the url in a browser and i got the following Request Header and Response Header Info.   **Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8** my servlet.xml :`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Originally this issue occurs when the request sends an accept header that differs from the response's content-type. I don't know if this is the case, there's not enough source provided.

However, another a bit more trickier situation when the same error occurs is when the framework is not able to convert the response to an appropriate representation, e.g. on account of bad getters/setters or missing dependencies.

In the code you posted I see an issue with your dependencies. [Spring 4.1 needs minimum Jackson 2.1](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/wiki/Migrating-from-earlier-versions-of-the-Spring-Framework#libraries), and in the version Jackson 2 and above a package change occurred from *codehaus* to *fasterxml*. Replace the two of your Jackson dependencies with the following one

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.2</version>
</dependency>
```

or better yet go for a newer version. Single dependency is enough it will transitively pull  `com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar` and `com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar`

Comment: The setter looks strange but it is not wrong. Works as intended.

Comment: you need to provide more info, record request and response headers and paste in the question

Comment: Hi there is nothing else that i have added , as in the documentation it was written that everything else will be handled by Adding the RestController and response body annotation. except that i have not added anything .

Comment: Request Method:GET
Status Code:406 Not Acceptable
Request Headersview source
Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Cache-Control:max-age=0
Connection:keep-alive
Host:localhost:8080
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36
Response Headersview source
Content-Language:en
Content-Length:1067
Content-Type:text/html;charset=utf-8
Date:Thu, 15 Jan 2015 05:14:29 GMT
Server:Apache-Coyote/1.1

Answer (score 0):

I think you might have to ensure that your Request is having the following in your header:

```
GET 
Accept: application/json
```